# Tensorflow roll tensor after concat crash my jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow2.0

When I try to roll two concatenate tensor it crash my notebook :
Please someone know what is incorrect here ? Thanks you very much

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2],dtype="int32")
y = tf.zeros(shape=(2),dtype="int32")
z = tf.concat([x,y],axis=0)
tf.roll(z,1,axis=0)
```

Comment: I get this `tf.Tensor([0 1 2 0], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)` on Google colab

Comment: Ok thanks ... I will try and compare versions